# How do you manually update a MySQL table's index?

Tags: mysql

I reset the previous index by accident, and now I need to manually update it so that index = number of rows in table.

What is the sql command for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1